# Efficient grouping of data in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to perform simple grouping of data in Spark (Scala). In particular, this is my initial data:

```
1, a, X
1, b, Y
2, a, Y
1, a, Y

val seqs = Seq((1, "a", "X"),(1, "b", "Y"),(2, "a", "Y"),(1, "a", "Y"))
```

I need to group it by the first key as follows:

```
1, (a, X), (b, Y), (a, Y)
2, (a, Y)
```

My initial idia was to use `DataFrame` and `groupBy`, but I read that this operation is very expensive and requires a complete reshuffle of all data.

So, what is the less expensive option to perform grouping? A concrete example would be appreciated.

Comment: but a group by is exactly what you wanted - and parallel processing is spark's strength, so you can do groupBy to RDD or Dataframe. An alternative is to do Reduce which is much more efficient, but the problem is you are left with 1 key value pair per group in the end.

Comment: You can't group things across partitions without doing a shuffle. Think about where the items need to go. It's expensive because it's _necessarily_ expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could potentially do something like this:

```
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((1, "a", "X"),(1, "b", "Y"),(2, "a", "Y"),(1, "a", "Y")))
  val mapping = rdd.map(x=>(x._1,List((x._2,x._3))))
  val result = mapping.reduceByKey((x,y) => (x ++ y))
```

This uses the reduceByKey, but the problem with all reduce process, you must end up with 1 key value pair per group. So in this case, you need to explicitly convert each of your values into Lists, so the reduce process can then merge them.

You may also consider looking at [combineByKey](http://www.edureka.co/blog/apache-spark-combinebykey-explained), which uses an internal reduce process

======EDIT======

As zero323 pointed out, reduce here will not increase the efficiency and on the contrary - the process will lose the optimization of groupByKey.

Comment: Thanks. Just a small question (I probably missed this detail in my explanation). My real data is in the format RDD[String]. So I do `val splitted = rdd.map(line => line.split(","))` in order to get particular values, e.g. `1`, `a`, `X`. The variable `splitted` is of the type `RDD[Array[String]]`. How should I apply `reduceByKey` to `splitted`?

Comment: @HackerDuck you need to map out the Array of Strings into your (Int,String,String) structure through a case class or something - it is general practice to map it through a case class because it also acts as the schema when you transform it in to a Dataframe (if you so desire).

Comment: What does `(x ++ y)` mean?

Comment: By the way I appreciate if you add a line of code showing how to print `result`, which in my case is `RDD[(String,List[(String,String)])]`

Comment: @HackerDuck `x++y` means merging the List x with List y, which in the context of the reduce operation, means collect all the values and put them in a List - and yes, your result would be key, List(Values) which is what group by generates.

Comment: This is not _much more efficient  than groupByKey_. In fact you're using the same general mechanism but without optimizations used by `groupByKey`.

Comment: @zero323 I would personally have used groupByKey, and I realize this reduce uses the same general mechanism. Is there a better method then - i.e. is combineByKey more efficient?

Comment: Unless you want to create something as sophisticated as external grouper then it is rather unlikely you'll be able to optimize beyond groupByKey (which a) uses mutable buffer b) disables map side combine).

Comment: @zero323 I see, I thought along the line of if you were able to optimize it using reduce - then this function would exist without much meaning - you are right and I've edited the answer.