# Cannot print the contents of RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I try to print the contents of my RDD `RDD[(String,List[(String,String)])]`:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val splitted = rdd.map(line => line.split(","))
val processed = splitted.map(x=>(x(1),List((x(0),x(2),x(3),x(4)))))
val grouped = processed.reduceByKey((x,y) => (x ++ y))
System.out.println(grouped)
```

However instead of getting the contents I see:

`ShuffledRDD[4] at reduceByKey at Consumer.scala:88`

UPDATE:

The content of TXT file:

```
100001082016,230,111,1,1 
100001082016,121,111,1,1
100001082016,110,111,1,1
```

UPDATE 2 (the whole code):

```
class Consumer()
{

def run() = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
                              .setAppName("TEST")
                              .setMaster("local[*]") 
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rdd = sc.textFile("file:///usr/test/myfile.txt")
    val splitted = rdd.map(line => line.split(","))
    val processed = splitted.map(x=>(x(1),List((x(0),x(2),x(3),x(4)))))
    val grouped = processed.reduceByKey((x,y) => (x ++ y))
    System.out.println(grouped)
}

}
```

Comment: What does the rest of the stacktrace say?

Comment: And in Scala, you'd do `println(grouped.collect())`. No need for System.out

Comment: @cricket_007: In this case I get `[Lscala.Tuple2;@5377414a`. The rest of stack is a standard Spark output e.g. `6/08/19 13:49:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at Consumer.scala:89, took 0.519500 s`, etc.

Comment: You are printing an Array of tuples using Java `System.out.println`. If you want to use the Scala Standard out, you only need `println(grouped.collect())` and you should get a `List[Tuple2]`

Comment: @cricket_007: Hmm, if I do `println(grouped.collect())`, I see `[Lscala.Tuple2;@5377414a` instead of the content, that's the problem. I want to see the content.

Comment: Are you getting the expected output from `splitted.collect()`?

Comment: @cricket_007: There seem to be an issue with reading from the file... in case of `println(splitted.collect())`, I get `[[Ljava.lang.String;@3976ebfa`. Please see my update - I posted the content of the TXT file.

Comment: Can you please show the complete Scala code as well? And your expected output?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have answered a similar question yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008732/saving-users-and-items-features-to-hdfs-in-spark-collaborative-filtering-rdd/39011568#39011568

Comment: @cricket_007: I posted the complete code.

Comment: I have downvoted this question nevertheless because I consider that it's not well researched and quite bad quality. It's easy to use a code that we don't understand http://stackoverflow.com/a/39037064/3415409

Comment: @eliasah -  I figured it was a `toString` problem, I'm still learning Scala myself ;)

Comment: This still isn't a complete piece of code. What is `rdd`? Where is the code that shows how you read the file?

Comment: We are all learning @cricket_007 :) The explanation about toString is in my answer for the link I've provided you before. And for more details it links to a full discussion about the topic.

Comment: @sebszyller `rdd` seems to be an `RDD[String]` if you look the OPs previous question. But this is not the issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no issue here :

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("100001082016,230,111,1,1","100001082016,121,111,1,1","100001082016,110,111,1,1"))
// rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> val splitted = rdd.map(line => line.split(","))
// splitted: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:29

scala> val processed = splitted.map(x=>(x(1),List((x(0),x(2),x(3),x(4)))))
// processed: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, String, String, String)])] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at <console>:31

scala> val grouped = processed.reduceByKey((x,y) => (x ++ y))
// grouped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, String, String, String)])] = ShuffledRDD[3] at reduceByKey at <console>:33

scala> grouped.collect().foreach(println)
// (121,List((100001082016,111,1,1)))
// (110,List((100001082016,111,1,1)))
// (230,List((100001082016,111,1,1)))
```

**The following is wrong.** It works as expect but you have to understand the language correctly to know what is expect :

```
scala> System.out.println(grouped)
// ShuffledRDD[3] at reduceByKey at <console>:33
```

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, if you wish to print a collection, you'll need to use the mkString method available for the collection that you'd need to print converting it into the format you'd want.

Comment: `grouped.collect()` works in the console because it treats printing an array specially. `println(grouped.collect())` _doesn't_ work as desired: just try `println(Array(1,2))`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I didn't say anything about `println(grouped.collect)` . Still println(grouped) will use the `toString method` of `ShuffledRDD`. I think that we both agree on that, thus works as expect.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov the grouped.collect here was just an example maybe I should remove it to avoid confusion.