# Not able to see RDD contents

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am using scala to create an RDD but when i am trying to see the contents of RDD i am getting below results

```
MapPartitionsRDD[25] at map at <console>:96
```

I want to see the contents of RDD how can i see that ?

below is my scala code:

```
 object WordCount {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxx/File")
     val word = textfile.filter(x => x.length >  0).map(_.split('|'))
     println(word)
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot print the contents of RDD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038249/cannot-print-the-contents-of-rdd)

Comment: @eliasah Thanks a lot for the link it is having some detailed explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an [output transformation (action)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions). e.g. use [`RDD.collect`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD):

```
object WordCount {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxx/File")
     val word = textfile.filter(x => x.length >  0).map(_.split('|'))
     word.collect().foreach(println)
   }
}
```

If you have an `Array[Array[T]]`, you'll need to `flatten` before using `foreach`:

```
word.collect().flatten.foreach(println)
```

Comment: I tried your way i am getting `[[Ljava.lang.String;@18e39f6f
` as my output

Comment: i tried with `word.collect().foreach(println)` i am getting `[Ljava.lang.String;@1ec0cf46
[Ljava.lang.String;@4680c70
[Ljava.lang.String;@4b088f52
[Ljava.lang.String;@1ef976fa
[Ljava.lang.String;@bf226f9
[Ljava.lang.String;@46dcab8f
[Ljava.lang.String;@41835da1
`

Comment: Looks like you have an `Array[Array[String]]`. You'll need to flatten first: `word.collect().flatten.foreach(println)`

Comment: this worked i am getting my results Thanks a lot. i have one doubt how to find that it is `Array[Array[String]]` ?

Comment: If you're using an IDE such as IntelliJ, you can `ALT + =` on `word` to check the return type.

Comment: Thanks for the help !!