# Transforming a collections of strings in an RDD

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hl7

I am trying to parse HL7 values for that i am using few jar files, those jar files parse HL7 values from string, i executed the code and it is working fine in scala but now i want the same thing to be run in scala for that i am using below code with the sample but i am getting the below error. So to solve the issue i want to convert `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]` to `String`.

**Code:**

```
 object ExampleUseTerser {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/File")
    val context : HapiContext = new DefaultHapiContext();
    val p  = context.getGenericParser();
    val hapiMsg  = p.parse(textfile);
    val terser  = new Terser(hapiMsg);
    val secondAllergyType:String  = terser.get("/PID-7");
    println(secondAllergyType);

  } 
}
```

**Update**

Sample :

```
PID|1|5897450M|58974650M|58977650M|CSTO^TES||19320722|F|||745 - 81 ST^^IAMI BEH^FL^341|||||||332165520
ORC||5033220|503320||||||20150202|||1689659096^HAM^MISH^^^^PI
OBR|1||64564|DF DEFAULT|||20150202|2015002||||||||16096^^^^^I|||||||||
HHH|1|NM|6690-2^^LN^0^^L||7|XE/UL|3.4-18||||F|||20150202| ^^L
HHH|9|NM|777-3^LOINC^LN^015172^PLATELETS^L||185|X10E3/UL|150-379||||F|||201202|TA   ^^L
HHH|10|NM|770-8^^LN^015107^^L||65|%|||||F|||20150202|TA   ^^L
HHH|11|NM|736-9^LOINC^LN^015123^^L||26|%|||||F|||20150202|TA   ^^L
HHH|12|NM|5905-5^LOINC^LN^015131^^L||8|%|||||F|||20150202|TA   ^^L
HHH|13|NM|713-8^LOINC^LN^015149^^L||1|%|||||F|||20150202|TA   ^^L
```

Error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
 required: String
           val hapiMsg  = p.parse(textfile);
```

Comment: What are you getting and what do you expect? Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: An `RDD` is a *Resilient Distributed **DataSet***, it isn't an abstraction of a single value, but over a collection of values. Using `toString` over a collection of values is almost always not what you want to do.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov let him crash a node or two :)

Comment: @sebszyller i have updated my question and added few more details.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i have updated my question. please check

Comment: What is `hapiMsg`? What are you actually trying to do here? Perhaps explain the flow of execution you're *expecting*, and not what you're currently *doing*.

Comment: it is a variable i created for parsing the data.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i want to read the HL7 data from hdfs and store the 7th coloumn of PID row in a variable for extracting those values i am using HAPI library which can extract values from HL7.

Comment: But you don't have a single value, do you? You're working on a file with multiple values. Do you want to extract *each values* HL7?

Comment: Yes i want to extract each value. I tried the same example in scala it worked fine but with spark it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're working with an `RDD`, you need to remember that the abstraction is over a *collection of values* (it's actually a little bit more complex, but lets leave it at that for the moment), and not a single value.

Given your example, we need to map over all the elements in the collection and try and extract their PID. We can do it using `mapPartitions` so we don't have to allocate a new `HapiContext` for each value:

```
object ExampleUseTerser {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/File")
    val parsedData = textfile.mapPartitions { it => 
      val context: HapiContext = new DefaultHapiContext()
      val parser = context.getGenericParser()

      it.map { file => 
        val hapiMsg = parser.parse(file)
        val terser = new Terser(hapiMsg)
        terser.get("/PID-7")
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

If you're testing this out and want to view the parsed files, you can use `RDD.collect` as [I've mentioned in my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123748/not-able-to-see-rdd-contents/39123782#39123782) (but of course *don't do that* when using this in any kind of production environment).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it solved my problem. I don't know how else to thank you for this.

Comment: i want to know one more thing is this code going to work if i am having multiple `PID` in my file ?

Comment: @animal It should work fine. Though if you returns multiple pid's, you'll be handling a `Seq[Seq[String]]`, so make sure you know which collections you're operating on.